# I cannot move my player to right on Godot

Tags: godot

I'm beginning with Godot making a simple Sprite which should move both left and right but when right key is pressed the `KinematicBody2D` doesn't move right. According to the logic it should does but it does not.

I leave the code below hoping someone could help me to find the error

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const VEL = 50
var vec_mov = Vector2()

func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

func _physics_process(delta):
   if(Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right")):
       vec_mov.x += VEL
   if(Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left")):
       vec_mov.x -= VEL
   else: 
       vec_mov.x = 0

   move_and_slide(vec_mov)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the code here:

```
   if(...):
       A
   if(...):
       B
   else: 
       C
```

You are causing it to go into C only if it does not go into B. The statement about A is a separate statement and has no effect. So the velocity value is getting turned off because you are not in B.

Try putting all the statements together like this:

```
   if(...):
       A
   elif(...):
       B
   else: 
       C
```

It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now its moving both sides and looks cool!  :D